# Fields over which a matrix is not invertible

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, finite-fields, inverse

I am trying to find the fields over which the matrix:

$\left(\begin{matrix} 
1 & 2 & 3 \\ 
0 & -1 & 2 \\ 
1 & 0 & -2  
\end{matrix}\right) $

is not invertible. I have calculated the determinant as 9. I know it is not invertible if detA=$0$. I believe the fields $F_1, F_3$ and $F_9$ both satisfy this (i.e. the factors of 9) but are there any more? Can it be proved these are the only ones?

Comment: What is $F_1$? A field with one element?

Comment: @awllower of course, $F_1$ cannot be a field as it cannot have a unique additive and multiplicative identity. My apologies!

Comment: For example, all the fields $F_{3^n}$ satisfy $3=0$, so also $9=0$.

Answer (score 3):

The determinant is $9,$ and $9=0$ in a field $F$ if and only if the characteristic of $F$ divides $9,$ i.e. if and only if $F$ has characteristic $3.$ For example, the algebraic closure of $\mathbb F_3$ satisfies this.
Hope this helps.
**Edit**
We have a ring homomorphism $\phi:\mathbb Z\rightarrow F,$ defined as $\phi(n)=n\cdot1_F, \forall n\in\mathbb Z.$
And the kernel $K$ is an ideal of $\mathbb Z;$ since $\mathbb Z$ is a principal ideal domain, this is generated by one single element, say $K=(n_0).$ Then we define $char(F)=n_0.$ And $9=0$ in $F$ if and only if $9\in K,$ so...?
Below is an elementary argument:
The characteristic of a field $F$ is defined as the smallest positive integer $n_F$ such that $n_F=0$ in $F,$ and, if such an integer does not exist, define $n_F=0.$
As an exercise, show that, if $k=0$ in $F$ for some integer $k,$ then $n_F\mid k.$ And the converse is obviously true, namely,

> An integer $k$ satisfies $k=0$ in $F$ if and only if $n_F\mid k.$

This should be an easy exercise, using [Euclidean division](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_division#Statement_of_the_theorem).

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand why 9=0 in a field where the characteristic divides 9. Can you explain this?

Comment: A lot of this notation and terminology is new to me!

Comment: I made an edit further; is this better?

Comment: I think so, I'm still a little confused why say $F_27$ has characteristic 3, and why this means 9=0?

Comment: @user43290: What is your definition of $F_{27}$?

Comment: @henningmakholm A field is a ring with unity such that the set of non-zero elements of K forms an
abelian group under multiplication. I am unsure what $F_{27}$ actually means.

Comment: @user43290: Okay, so what is your definition of $F_9$ which you claim is a solution?

Comment: The set of integers modulo 9 @henningmakholm

Comment: @user43290 And why is that set a field? What is the inverse of $3\pmod9?$

Comment: @user43290: Ah, there's your trouble. The set of integers modulo 9 **is not a field**, since there's no multiplicative inverse of $3$ (or $6$) there. Instead the field with $9$ elements can be constructed as $\mathbb Z_3/\langle X^2+1\rangle$. Incidentally, this happens to be equivalent to $\mathbb Z_3+i\mathbb Z_3$, the Gaussian integers modulo $3$.

Comment: @henningmakholm I'm afraid I don't know what the Gaussian integers are. However, the question asks for me to find 'a field' over which the matrix is not invertible, so perhaps I should just find the most simple case?

Comment: @user43290: If you just need to find _some_ field where the matrix is not invertible, $\mathbb F_3$ should suffice fine. (The Gaussian integers are the complex numbers whose real and imaginary components are both integers, such as $5-27i$, but not $\frac12+i$ or $2\pi i$).

Comment: @henningmakholm How about $Z_3$? Am I right in thinking that is a field that suffices?

Comment: @user43290: $\mathbb Z_3$ and $\mathbb F_3$ are two names for the same object, so yes. (This identity hold for _prime_ suffixes).

Answer (score 1):

The [field with one element](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_with_one_element) is not actually a field.

On the other hand, $\mathbb F_3$, $\mathbb F_9$, $\mathbb F_{27}$ and so forth all have *characteristic 3* and therefore satisfy the equation $9=0$, so those work. Similarly all infinite fields of characteristic 3 will work too.

Comment: Can you explain why $F_{27}$ satisfies please?

Comment: @user43290: $\mathbb F_{27}$, like every other fields whose size is a power of $3$, has caracteristic $3$ and therefore $1+1+1=0$ in that field. Be sure not to confuse $\mathbb F_{27}$ with the ring of integers modulo $27$ -- the latter is not a field (for example $3$ has no inverse)!